# Loggly performance

Tags: python, logging

I'm getting ready to deploy an app to Heroku and I'm considering adding Loggly as a plugin.  I love the idea of being able to aggregate and search my logs more easily, but I'm a bit concerned about what kind of performance hit I might take because of it.  Any experiences (good or bad) out there with Loggly?

Just as a note: I'm using Python with Django 1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for future reference for people...  I tried loggly out and was generally very pleased with them.  While I never did any formal benchmarking tests (with our without them).  Any performance issues were not noticeable to me.

Comment: @Craig - I'm glad my "not constructive" question was of some benefit to you.  The SO's question police suck.